# MySql result won't update after new changes

Tags: mysql, sql

So I made a change from 'Chemistry' to 'Physic' on 'major' column but as soon I executed it nothing changes and shows the same result. Why? (I used MySql Workbench)

Here's the original code:

```
   CREATE TABLE people_data1 (
        id INT,
        username VARCHAR(20),
        major VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE,
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );
    # Insert some data into the table 
    INSERT INTO people_data1(id,username) VALUES(3,'Clara'); # Person with no major
    INSERT INTO people_data1 VALUES(51,'Mr Bald','Chemistry'); # Change to 'Physic'

    SELECT * FROM people_data1;
```

The new one:

```
CREATE TABLE people_data1 (
    id INT,
    username VARCHAR(20),
    major VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
# Insert some data into the table 
INSERT INTO people_data1(id,username) VALUES(3,'Clara'); # Person with no major
INSERT INTO people_data1 VALUES(51,'Mr Bald','Physic');

SELECT * FROM people_data1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Inserts add *new* records; you want an update here:

```sql
UPDATE people_data1
SET major = 'Physics'
WHERE id = 51;
```

Run this update after your first two insert statements to get your desired results.